# save pdf locally in IOS

Tags: ios, quartz-2d

hi i am created pdf file using Quartz framework in IOS.i need to download that pdf file in local folder like saving images in simulator.any one tell me how to do this.

my code for creating pdf

```
     -(NSString*)getPDFFileName
     {
     NSString* fileName = @"Invoice.PDF";

     NSArray *arrayPaths =
     NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(
                                    NSDocumentDirectory,
                                    NSUserDomainMask,
                                    YES);
     NSString *path = [arrayPaths objectAtIndex:0];
     NSString* pdfFileName = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];

     return pdfFileName;

    }

    -(void)showPDFFile


    {
    NSString* fileName = @"Invoice.PDF";

    NSArray *arrayPaths =
    NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(
                                    NSDocumentDirectory,
                                    NSUserDomainMask,
                                    YES);
    NSString *path = [arrayPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString* pdfFileName = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];

    UIWebView* webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:pdfFileName];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [webView setScalesPageToFit:YES];
    [webView loadRequest:request];

    [self.view addSubview:webView];    
     }

  - (void)viewDidLoad
   {
  NSString* fileName = [self getPDFFileName];

  [PDFRenderer drawPDF:fileName];
  [self showPDFFile];

  [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

thanks in advance..

Comment: From where you are getting the file? Are you creating in the application and than storing or you are downloading it from remote server and than storing?

Comment: i am creating pdf page with in app.i need to save that

Answer (score 2):

This will do what you need.

```
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectoryPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *pdfDirectoryString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/YOUR_FILE_NAME", documentsDirectoryPath];

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![YOUR_PDF_DATA writeToFile:pdfDirectoryString options:NSDataWritingAtomic error:&error])
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
```

Comment: here YOUR_PDF_DATA means what i give .

Comment: Storing in document directory without user interaction may result in rejection of your app on apple store. Store it in Library directory instead.

Comment: App will not get rejected if you store in document directory.. so you can proceed saving it in document directory.

Comment: I've never had an app rejected for that ... You can save files the user has created. Guess it depends if the user is creating his PDF.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

For saving PDF in Document Directory

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSData *data = [PDFImageConverter convertImageToPDF:screenShot]; // convert PDF to data
NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",[docArr objectAtIndex:0],[NSString stringWithFormat:@"userDetails.pdf"]];
[data writeToFile:path atomically:NO];
```

To retrieve and display in web view

```
NSArray     *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString    *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *pdfPathString =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"userDetails.pdf"]]];
NSURL *targetURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:pdfPathString];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:targetURL];
[contentWebview loadRequest:request];
```